# received religion

Tags: vocabulary

Does anyone know what "received religion" means?

Here's the link to the book where I found it: [Hungary's Long Nineteenth Century](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=nzW8aApInY8C&pg=PA417&lpg=PA417&dq=%22received%20religion%22&source=bl&ots=69i48lLzmb&sig=mtczGYthgkzQ_qrJSavVW_rQq70&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=RrT4VKPIMuuHsQT6gYKgCg&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22received%20religion%22&f=false)

Does it mean something like the "official religion" or "legitimate religion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wish to allude to the origins of the word *received*.

*Receive* is different from *accept*.

*Accept* signifies that the purveyor or initiator of the transaction is the *acceptor*. For example, "I accept your lifestyle, even though I abhor it."

*Receive* signifies that the purveyor or initiator of the transaction is the giver offering the gift. Therefore, you would receive what is being offered.

I also wish to further reference the basic religious background that has made the participle *received* nearly synonymous to *authorised*. One has to accept, yes accept, that much of English linguistic culture is drawn from scriptures used by Christianity.

Pauline doctrine, especially the book of Romans has had a huge impact on the use of the word *receive*, where salvation is said to be "freely" (but monopolistically) offered by the source said to be the only source *authorised* to offer it. Wherefore, Pauline doctrine admonishes that devotees would receive this gift from the only one who is able to supply it.

The word *receive* has also been obsessively promoted by Calvinism, which had a significant influence on modernization as well as liberation of European culture from the strictures of Roman Catholicism. Calvinists tend to believe that even the tendency to receive salvation itself is a divinely *authorised* and predetermined gift that a devotee would *receive*.

We know that worldly govts and organisations prior to success of modern atheistic movements, had for centuries persistently attempted to project themselves as being agents appointed by Divine Power. For example, the *Received Authorised Version* of the Bible, or "Textus Receptus". Implying that their version is *authorised* and initiated by Divine agency. All others are inferior.

Another example is *received pronunciation* of the English language. Perhaps, authorised by elitist (or even royal) decree for its speakers to *receive* it.

The origin of the word [*receive* is the Latin *recipere*, past participle *receptus*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/receive#English).

Take note that the Hebrew equivalent that carries the meaning of *receive* is the root (קבל) QBL, from which the term *Qabalah* is derived.

One has to dwell further into the meaning of the Latin *recipere*, and hence its past participle *receptus*. It means to return, restore, recover, take back.

Incidentally, the Latin word has a near exact Hebrew equivalent (שב), which is the root word for return, repeat, recycle, sabbath, sit, restore, repent, restore.

There is a pattern in European religion where egalitarian concepts of humility are transformed into concepts of elitism, like the washing of feet by Jesus to signify an act of humility by the offeror, into an act of superiority by a figure of authority.

So that salvation is to be received from the only one authorised to offer it, rather than from the one capable of offering it. And where the Hebrew word for repentance actually means restoration and returning to the state of origin, but after centuries of institutionalisation, the modern meaning tends to imply submitting one's rebellious self to an authority.

Perhaps following that pattern, the Latin word *recipere* also had been transformed into a word that signifies condescension by, and submission to, an authority. All other sources are inferior.

Comment: *Liberation* does not necessarily mean *progress*.

Answer (score 2):

From the preceding sentence and associated footnote in your linked text:

> Article XXVI of 1790 referred to the Lutheran and Calvinist Churches as *in sensu pacificationem receptis.*<sup>35</sup>
>
> <sup>35</sup> Section 13, the context implies the Lutheran and the Calvinist Churches which are contrasted with the Catholic Church. The section alludes to the Vienna Peace of 1606. *(Ad primium art.)* Art. 1 of 1608 *ante cor* and to Section 5 Art of 1647. **The influence of the Transylvanian legal term *recepta religio* is very probable.**

From the first Google result for “received religion”:

> **A "received" religion means an authorized or state-supported religion or denomination, as opposed to an "accepted" religion whose exercise is tolerated but not affirmatively sponsored.** The term comes from a distinction in Transylvanian law, beginning with a proclamation by the Diet of Torda in January 1568 recognizing and guaranteeing freedom of worship for Roman Catholicism, Calvinism, Lutheranism, and Unitarianism. Other religions were later "received" as well.
>
> The term can also mean a religion "received" from one's community or upbringing, as opposed to a personal faith developed from personal experience or revelation.
> <sub>Source: [Straight Dope Message Board > What is a "Received Religion"?](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=154475)</sub>

(emphasis mine in both cases)

Comment: So I guess it could mean "official religion" based on this: A "received" religion means an authorized or state-supported religion or denomination, as opposed to an "accepted" religion whose exercise is tolerated but not affirmatively sponsored.

Comment: I've already quoted this source. You should check to see if other answers contain a source before you post it.

Comment: I know you've already quoted it, Nicole. I'm just saying that, based on that specific part of the quote, I came to my conclusion. I'm sorry for not making it clear.

Comment: @Nicole Your response did not exist when I authored mine.

Comment: @MariaM. Yes, I'd say "official religion" is a good replacement.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Search of "received religion" led to this definition:

> A "received" religion means an authorized or state-supported religion or denomination, as opposed to an "accepted" religion whose exercise is tolerated but not affirmatively sponsored. The term comes from a distinction in Transylvanian law, beginning with a proclamation by the Diet of Torda in January 1568 recognizing and guaranteeing freedom of worship for Roman Catholicism, Calvinism, Lutheranism, and Unitarianism. Other religions were later "received" as well.
>
> The term can also mean a religion "received" from one's community or upbringing, as opposed to a personal faith developed from personal experience or revelation.
>
> Source: [The Straight Dope](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/archive/index.php/t-154475.html)